# dispatch.yaml - Problem accessing Subdomain on App Engine Standard

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have the following static webpage that I have deployed on App Engine:

[image]

> I am using Node.js runtime because the actual app I want to deploy is
> a Vue.js application.

When I deploy I am able to access the application on the default url that is provided by App Engine that looks like this https://dev-xxxxx.uc.r.appspot.com. The CSS is applied perfectly.

[image]

I have created a dispatch.yaml that maps the **dev** service to my custom subdomain **dev.example.com**:

```
dispatch:
   - url: "dev.example.com/"
     service: dev
```

but when i access the webpage using my custom domain the CSS isn't loaded.. does anyone know why this is happening or what I have missed?
[image]

> This is happening on Javascript files too hence my Vue.js app isn't
> loading when accessed via the custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

okay i have figured it out, on the dispatch.yaml i had to add an asterisk, like so

```
dispatch:
   - url: "dev.example.com/*"
     service: dev
```

Not sure why it works...the only reason i can think of is the url uses regex to route.

Comment: `*` is a wildcard character and your URL syntax defines that the dispatch.yaml will send any path that begins with “dev.example.com/” to the dev service. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/dispatch-yaml#example